How is it possible to get clean data from the view in jsViews?
I have the following data in my view
  let data = {
               selectedEntry: 0,
               selectedMessage: 1,
               roles: roles,
               entries: [{messages: [...]}, {messages: [...]}, ...]
            };

and I modify data.entries in some handlers like:
removeEntry: function(i) {
   $.observable(this.entries).remove(i);
},
removeMessage: function(i, j) {
   $.observable(this.entries[i].messages).remove(j);
},

also I have observer that is triggered on every data modification and this way I can get access to updated data and send save it somewhere for other scripts..
 $.observe(data, "entries", function(ev, eventArgs, newTagCtxs){
    $('#root-selector-here').data("entries", data.entries);
 });

but I have discovered that data.entries include not only my data but different jQuery objects, I think jsViews adds them. I don't need those objects and need just clean data. How can I get it? Perhaps there is any special method to get clean data?

I have found that this question is duplicate of another question and there is a solution for the problem.

Yes, you are right. That question is a duplicate, and the response is here.
